# Given a big list of urls, what is a way to check which are active/inactive?

Tags: python

Suppose I was giving this list of urls:

> website.com/thispage
>
> website.com/thatpage
>
> website.com/thispageagain
>
> website.com/thatpageagain
>
> website.com/morepages

... could possibly be over say 1k urls.

What is the best/easiest way to kinda loop through this list and check whether or not the page is up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python verify url goes to a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041443/python-verify-url-goes-to-a-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform a HEAD request on each of them.

Use this library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

```
requests.head('http://httpbin.org/get').status_code
```

Comment: can provide me a snippet? i remember using something a while back with python but cant think of the name of the module.

Comment: @yaojiang Why don't you look at this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ and come back when you hit a snag with your own code.

Comment: wonderful, ill check that out! i was thinking something like "url.open(site).getcode" but im sure the syntax and function names are all wrong.

Comment: @yaojiang It's about that easy with `requests`

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example in Python

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http()
listUrls = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.xkcd.com','http://somebadurl.com']
count = 0

for each in listUrls:
    try:
        response, content = h.request(listUrls[count])
        if response.status==200:
            print "UP"
    except httplib2.ServerNotFoundError:
        print "DOWN"
    count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an SO answer showing how to perform HEAD requests in Python:

[How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Open a pool of threads, open a Url for each, wait for a 200 or a 404. Rinse and repeat.