# Getting this weird "invalid syntax" error when using urllib3/requests

Tags: python, installation, python-requests, urllib3

Following what others suggested in: [Given a big list of urls, what is a way to check which are active/inactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424753/given-a-big-list-of-urls-what-is-a-way-to-check-which-are-active-inactive)

Getting the error when trying to install requests, using urllib3.

Trying to install requests.

```
C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop>setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\requests\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\requests\utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\requests\compat.py", line 95, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\My Downloads\requests-develop\requests-develop\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 434
    except Empty as e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Trying to use urllib3.

```
C:\Users\yao\Desktop\ad stuff\find urls>reqs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yao\Desktop\ad stuff\find urls\reqs.py", line 1, in <module>
    import re, csv, urllib3
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\urllib3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\urllib3-dev-py2.5.egg\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 435
    except Empty as e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just recently installed setuptools, pip, requests, urllib3. In that order. Did I mess up anything? Using python 2.5 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib3` requires Python 2.6 or greater. From [their README](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3#readme):

> - Tested on Python 2.6+ and Python 3.2+

They dropped support for Python 2.5 [in version 1.2, which was released in January 2012](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#12-2012-01-29):

> Dropped Python 2.5 support (tested on 2.6.7, 2.7.2)

Python 2.6 added a new syntax for handling exceptions, as you can read in [What’s New in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html):

> Alternate syntax for catching exceptions: `except TypeError as exc`.

`urllib3` now uses this syntax, but you're trying to run it on Python 2.5 which does not support it.

Comment: weird, i have install python 2.7 as well, but it seems like everything is using python 2.5, how can i fix that?

Comment: You seem to be using Windows. I don't, so I'm afraid I don't know the answer. On Linux/Mac OS, I would just replace every reference to `python` or `python2.5` with `python2.7`, either in the file I'm executing or the commands I'm using to execute it.