# Check a set of hyperlinks active and inactive status in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

Basically, I am new to python. I have a set of URLs in an excel file and I want to check whether the links are active or inactive and save the active or inactive status column along with the URL column in a new excel file. I found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13425507/16786413) working fine but I am unsure of implementing this with excel. can anyone pls help to solve this?

[EXCEL before it goes through python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMlWx.png)

I want something like this from the above

[Excel after it went through python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TuBJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
import httplib2
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

h = httplib2.Http()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if("http" in str(row["urls"])):
        try:
            response, content = h.request(row["urls"])
            if response.status == 200:
                row["status"] = "active"
        except httplib2.ServerNotFoundError:
            row["status"] = "inactive"
    else:
        row["status"] = "No link"

print(df)
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.