# Why would HTTPConnection not work? nonnumeric port

Tags: python, httplib

I'm trying to use httplib to check if each url in a list of 30k+ websites still works. Each url is read in from a .csv file, and into a matrix, and then that matrix goes through a for-loop for each url in the file. Afterwards, (where my problem is), I run a function, runInternet(url), which takes in the url string, and returns true if the url works, and false if it doesn't.
I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041443/python-verify-url-goes-to-a-page) as my baseline, and have also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778435/python-check-if-website-exists). While I've tried both, I don't quite understand the latter, and neither works...

```
def runInternet(url):
    try:
        page = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
        page.connect()
    except httplib.HTTPException as e:
        return False
    return True
```

However, afterwards, all the links are stated as broken! I randomly chose a few that worked, and they work when I input them into my browser...so what's happening? I've narrowed down the problem spot to this line:
        page = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)

Edit: I tried inputting 'www.google.com' in exchange for the url, and the program works, and when I try printing e, it says nonnumeric port...

Comment: Don't use low(ish)-level HTTP interfaces like the `httplib` - it won't handle a lot of things for you, including modifiers, redirects, cookies... Use at least `urllib/urllib2` or, even better, the `requests` module. If you still insist, at least provide a sample of your data and how are you calling your function as, in theory, it should work for simple and direct URLs just fine.

Comment: I did initially try using urllib2, but it ended up being way too slow, and crashed on me after it hit the ~2100 mark. But I'll look into requests to see if it works better!

Answer (score 0):

You could troubleshoot this by allowing the `HTTPException` to propagate instead of catching it.  The specific exception type would likely help understand what is wrong.

I suspect though that the problem is this line:

```
page = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
```

The first argument to the constructor is not a URL.  Instead, it's a host name.  For example, this code sample passing a URL to the constructor fails:

```
page = httplib.HTTPConnection('https://www.google.com/')
page.connect()

httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//www.google.com/'
```

Instead, if I pass host name to the constructor, and then URL to the `request` method, then it works:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.google.com')
conn.request('GET', '/')
resp = conn.getresponse()
print resp.status, resp.reason

200 OK
```

For reference, here is the relevant abridged documentation of `HTTPConnection`:

```
class HTTPConnection
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, host, port=None, strict=None, timeout=<object object>, source_address=None)
 ...
 |  request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={})
 |      Send a complete request to the server.
```